# Need help selecting the right speed controller for a 3-phase AC motor

Tags: motor, ac, motor-controller, three-phase

[image]
This a three-phase single-volt 5-HP AC motor salvaged from a treadmill with a busted controller board.

The goal is to salvage the treadmill. Originally I was trying to repair the controller board.

I've decided to try a simpler approach of replacing all the digital stuff with just a basic manual motor speed controller. But I'm having trouble selecting the right part for the job.

More about the motor. Six wires in total. Three wires control the phases, one for ground, the other two are thermostat leads.

All I'm really looking for is a hand dial that controls speed reliably and smoothly and doesn't burn out the motor or create jerky motion. My understanding is that some sort of VFD regulator is required. But I'm having trouble selecting one that would result in reasonably smooth performance from 0 mph to a reasonably high speed without damaging the motor.

Speed/distance sensors and digital interfaces are cool, but maybe in some future project. I need to walk before I run. Pun intended.

Comment: Yes you need a 1 to 3ph VFD box rated for 5Hp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motor current rating indicates that the motor is not a 5 Hp motor by international standards. You should be looking for a 3 Hp VFD. There VFDs on the market at that power level that can provide the required output voltage and current with single-phase input power. There are models rated for 120 V, single-phase input and 230 V, three-phase output.

You don't need one of the highest performance models on the market, but you need more than a variable-torque model that is designed for fan or pump duty. The fan and pump VFDs are often designated as "standard duty" while the models that have higher starting torque and better low-speed performance are often called "heavy duty." You may find different terminology used.

Most of the ability to operate at low speed without burning out the motor is in the motor design. The motor that you have was designed for use in a treadmill. It is marked 5 Hp with a current rating that is more like 2.5 Hp or less. You don't need 5 Hp for a treadmill, but you do need a motor that can provide the torque of a smaller motor at low speed with continous operation. That is what the manufacturer is really trying to sell my calling it 5 Hp.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So far all the 3HP vhds that accept single phase 120v input are incapable of 220v output. I'm not sure how important of a factor that is in my selection process, can you give any examples to a VFD that youre describing?

Comment: I was thinking that I had seen a 120V input / 230 V output VFD for 3 Hp, but when I looked again I found that I must have read the selection chart wrong. I looked in a few other places and only found one that was a company that have not heard of before and provided little information about the product. There are a lot of manufacturers, so further searching might turn up something.

Comment: I ended up ordering this one. It's a Westinghouse TECO VFD with about 1hp support but it seems quite rugged and programmable. https://www.wolfautomation.com/vfd-1hp-115v-single-phase-ip20-med-duty/ I know this question is closed but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: That is probably a reasonable alternative to try. You can contact me through the web site on my profile.

Comment: Charles thanks a bunch! The Westinghouse TECO was an ideal fit for the job. I was immediately able to dial in settings like pwm modulation and carrier frequency to make the engine run quietly and max frequency to set an appropriate max speed. I just finished a 90-minute run no issues whatsoever. Plus there's some customizations like plugging in an external potentiometer. This is quite a well-built flexible little box! I'm still sifting through the manual which is substantial for additional tweaks. Not only did this work it's been a really fun learning exercise. Thanks for your expertise.